# Differentiating between prime/semi-prime and other integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

Does there exist a test that checks if a number is prime or a semi prime in polynomial time?

I am aware that AKS can be used to check primality but what about semi primality?

==================================================================

Additional Note:

Do there exist algorithms that cannot differentiate between primes and semi-primes but can differentiate either of those two from normal integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an open problem.  As far as anyone knows it is as hard as factoring which is not known to be in $P$.  A related problem which is also not known to be in $P$ is determining if a number has an even or odd number of prime factors.